# How to make variable global in javascript

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function (){
$(".available-room").change(function(){

        var id = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev('td').parent().attr('id');
   **// How can i use var id in below function.**

 });
 }); 


 </script>


 <script>
 function book()
 {
  alert (id);  **//How can i make it work here.**    

 var dataString = 'hotelId=' + '1';

 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/room_booking/book_now' ;?>",
 data: dataString,
 success: function(msgs) 
    {

        $("#room_book").html(msgs);

    }
 });
 }
 </script>
```

Hi, I am trying to use variable declared in one script to another script inside function as mentioned above. How can i do it. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Removing `var` declarative statement will put `id` on global scope. But why don't you call book() method from onchange event??? `$(".available-room").change(book);` then define `id` inside book method

Comment: I'm quite curious why is it needed to put another script tag.

Comment: make the variable global, for that declare it outside the function, in `$(document).ready`

Comment: book() method is also called when button is clicked which has onclick event. so i dont call it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope of variables is what you are looking for

```
<script>
var id;
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".available-room").change(function(){    
        id = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev('td').parent().attr('id');
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put id on global scope.

Trythis

```
    <script>
    var id;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".available-room").change(function () {
            id = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev('td').parent().attr('id');
        });
    });
  </script>
```

When book function is called that id hold the value